# Estimating the size of my population

Tags: statistics, estimation, experimental-mathematics

I have a following problem:

Imagine you have a hat with many different balls in it and you want to estimate, how many balls are totally in the hat. The only think you are allowed to do is to take one ball at the time, write down its ID and put it back.

I would like to obtain a reasonable guess of the total count of balls in finite time (of course, the longer I do my observation, the more accurate result I get). Or better, how my guess evolves in time with my observation.

I'm pretty sure the problem has been already solved, I just couldn't found anything similar on the internet.

Motivation: for example you hear to a radio station and you want to guess, how many songs they have in total.

Thank you very much for helping :)

Comment: The usual way is called [mark and recapture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture).

Comment: Yeah, I know this method. But it is applicable only when you can capture a sample at once...not if you take individuals one by one..

Comment: You mention the balls have ID numbers. Are those ID numbers consecutive: 1, 2, 3, ..., N, where N is the total number of balls? (Your radio example indicates this is NOT true. But the library of songs a radio station has can evolve with time.) As stated, I find this question a bit too vague for a unique solution.Any clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: You can imagine every ball has a different colour. With ID 1..N would occur a problem that if you in the first try get a ball with number k, you would immediately know, there are at least k balls.
And of course, we suppose the number of balls doesn't change in time.
Did I help?